# Cypress test validation for uppercase

Tags: validation, cypress, chai

I have function to convert text to uppercase, what I want to do is to write test in cypress for the function and print the result in HTML

Here the function :

```js
module.exports = () => ({
  upperCaseName: (name) => {
    return name.toUpperCase()
  }
});
```

Here I print it :

```html
<h1 cy-data='uppercase'> the result </h1>
```

How I should write the test? I know I could do this:

```js
cy.get('[cy-data=uppercase]').contains('the result')
```

but I want something like this:

```js
cy.get('[cy-data=uppercase]').to.be.upperCase
```

Comment: You want to check that the text `the result` is uppercase ?

Comment: yes that what i want @AlapanDas

Comment: is it possible ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about

```js
cy.get('[cy-data=uppercase]').contains('THE RESULT', { matchCase: true })
```

but `{ matchCase: true }` is the default setting, so can be just

```js
cy.get('[cy-data=uppercase]').contains('THE RESULT')
```

---

**Custom Chai assertion for uppercase**

```js
window.chai.Assertion.addProperty('uppercase', function () {
  var obj = this._obj;
  new chai.Assertion(obj).to.be.a('string');

  this.assert(
      obj === obj.toUpperCase()
    , 'expected #{this} to be all uppercase'    // error message when fail for normal
    , 'expected #{this} to not be all uppercase'  // error message when fail for negated
  );
});

it('test for upper case (and not uppercase)', () => {

  cy.get('[cy-data=uppercase]').invoke('text').should('be.uppercase')
  cy.get('[cy-data=lowercase]').invoke('text').should('not.be.uppercase')
  
})
```

Extends internal Cypress version of Chai with new assertion, works in `.should()` with retry and timeout as well.

---

Or without custom chai assertion

```js
it('test for upper case (and not uppercase)', () => {

  cy.get('[cy-data=uppercase]').invoke('text')
    .should(text => expect(text).to.eq(text.toUpperCase())

  cy.get('[cy-data=lowercase]').invoke('text')
    .should(text => expect(text).not.to.eq(text.toUpperCase())
  
})
```

Comment: thank you so much , but i could do that but what i want to check the uppercase with out writting what it contains

Comment: One way is a custom chai - will post it.

Comment: i didnt understand what do you mean

Comment: I missed `.invoke('text')` - please use this in command chain.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex as well to check that the text has uppercase or not.

```
cy.get('[cy-data=uppercase]')
  .invoke('text')
  .should('match', /\b[A-Z]+\b/)
```

To check if everything in the sentence is in uppercase along with special characters you can use the regex `^[^a-z]*$`

```
cy.get('[cy-data=uppercase]')
  .invoke('text')
  .should('match', /^[^a-z]*$/)
```

You can play around with regex as per your requirement.

Comment: Glad you were able to figure it out :)

Comment: @simao beware this will give false positive if there are two words - e.g "UPPER case" will pass.